# Choosing Between Additive and Multiplicative Model?

Tags: time-series, model-selection, seasonality

I have a set of data that I am currently analysing.

I am having difficulty in deciding whether an *Additive model* should be used to forecast the data, or if I should use a *Multiplicative model*.

I know the difference between the two, and I can apply the correct model when the raw data is linear...but in this case, my data is non linear.

I have attached a time-series of my data - which of the two models should I use and why?

(My instinct is to go with the Additive Model on the basis that the magnitude of the seasonal fluctuations (or the variation around the trend-cycle) doesn't appear to vary with the level of the time series.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would go for additive too. As your apparent signal seems of low frequency, you can go a little beyond, at least empirically. You can check for instance  the homoscedasticity of  finite differences of the data (first or second order). This would act as a very crude high-pass filter, where you could expect the noise to be dominant.

If your signal is much longer, moving windows and Fourier transforms could be of help.

However, as for forecasting, you can perform both models in parallel, and  decide which one you apply based, for instance, on the best performance of one of them based on past statistics. This is a heuristic method that I have recently used in the prediction of outcomes for hybrid system co-simulation, where no model is known: perform different extrapolations in parallel, very fast, and decide. It is not very theoretical, but it  works well on our data.

If interested, I could develop. The reference is called: [CHOPtrey: contextual online polynomial extrapolation for enhanced multi-core co-simulation of complex systems](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.09261)

As the data is quite short, and I am not sure we have a full seasonal period, I tried to perform some Fourier analysis on the data, its gradient and Laplacian. The fluctuation seems to be quite periodic, so on the bottom plot I have attempted to design a "filtering" moving average. The residue does not vary in amplitude a lot. It really does not seem to be random.

[image: Fourier type tests]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Very helpful and informative! I will be using some holdback data for the forecast, so in your opinion, what would be the best and simplest statistical test that I can use on the 'out of sample (holdback) data' to test the forecasts accuracy?

Comment: @JonasBlaps Do you have the possibility to share the data?

Comment: Using holdback data from one origin can be flawed when there are anomalies in the holdout data.Optimally predicting bad data can lead to bad model selection. This is often  called "the tail wagging the dog syndrome"

Comment: @IrishStat Indeed, I was about to suggest an exponentially weighted criterion (in the spirit of EWMA) that allows to progressively forget the past past

Comment: Rather than assume any form of a weighted average it is far better to determine the optimal form via ARIMA while taking into account any idebtifiable deterministic structure such as level shifts/trends/seasonal pulses and of course pulses.

Comment: @LaurentDuval Of course. Data is pasted below. Wasn't sure how to add it in Excel format so I have pasted the raw data here:

3010
3246
3618
4327
3695
4218
4671
5140
4411
4314
4844
5612
4562
5306
5239
5894
5166
5228
5223
5921
4672
4641
4746
5665
4419
4388
4811
5464
4257
4333
4180
4820
3405
3623
3778
4094
3626
3401
3564
4221
3136
3595
3610
4301
3220
3094
3624
4150
3262
3196
3430
4130
3403
3414
3652
4511
3426
3437

Comment: @JonasBlaps Did some very modest steps. Is your data always this short?

Comment: @LaurentDuval Masterful work gentlemen. Very helpful indeed!

I have so far created 1) Linear Model, 2)Cubic Model and 3) ARIMA Model for the same data simply to demonstrate the different forecasts that are available. If i were to compare the forecast accuracy of each of the 3 models, which statistical test would be the most simplest and suitable? I was considering doing the Diebold-Mariano test but I am having difficulties calculating this. Ideally I'm looking for a very simple test other than the usual MAPE, MSE, MAD etc. Thanks gents!

Comment: If you wanted to compare your three models and the more comprehensive one that I presented I would position the forecast origin at period 44 and predict out  4 periods , 45 and predict out 4 periods,,,,,,,, ... period 51 and predict out 4 periods. Thus I would have 8 samples (not one) to assess accuracy probably using MAPE

Answer (score 2):

I took the 55 values and used AUTOBOX to automatically detect a hybrid model possibly including deterministic structure as well as ARIMA structure. Th[image]e plot of the original data and the ACF plot of the [image] original series is here. AUTOBOX concluded that a single trend and 3 seasonal dummies were more appropriate tham SARIMA while also including AR structure of order 1 . Here is the model [image]      AND  here  [image] with the following statistical summaries [image] .

The residual plot is here suggesting sufficiency [image] with the companion ACF of the residuals here [image].

The Actual, Fit and Forecast plot is here [image] and the OUTLIER adusted plot clearly suggesting the need for the 4 pulses in the model [image] . Finally the Fo[image]recast plot is here for the next 8 periods.

Transformations such as logarithms or multiplicative models need to be justified and suggested by the data or by the user who has certain domain knowledge. This was not so in this case. See here for when power transforms are needed [When (and why) should you take the log of a distribution (of numbers)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18844/when-and-why-should-you-take-the-log-of-a-distribution-of-numbers) . Note that AUTOBOX essentially converged on the HW Additive Seasonal Model with TREND and 4 anomalies and a highly significant AR(1) coefficient.

COMMENTS FOR LAURENT:

Three of the four deterministic comments were required (Trend,Seasonal(QUARTERLY) Dummies and Pulses) while also needing the AR(1) structure to deal with short-term memory.

Comment: Grateful for the details